# Theory: Azure Websockets

Tags: c#, azure, kubernetes, websocket, azure-durable-functions

Is it possible to consume an external (to Azure) API that requires you to establish a wss connection to receive notifications of changes in some kind of Azure container (Kubernetes/Durable Function)?

Or do I need to run a Virtual Machine with a background service keeping the socket alive until it's got no more data to send (hours). No UI.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-overview?tabs=csharp

Durable functions look promising but I'm unsure if these will cover my requirements.
Any advice welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should be able to use WebSocket connections to services deployed on Kubernetes. And also the other way around where services in Kubernetes is WebSocket clients with connections to external services.

Comment: Great, I will have a look into it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested, but Azure Web App supports Web Socket. As you can host Azure Functions in the same App Service which is running your web app, I think it's possible to support web sockets on your functions with durable function.

Another point that leads me to think this, is the native support of Azure Functions to SignalR Service, which runs on Web Socket too.

Comment: Thanks, I’ll try a durable function with a web socket listener tomorrow if this is the case. 

SignalR is more ‘pushing’ to the websocket client. In this scenario my durable function is the client and I want be listening to the event handlers for a couple of hours before being closed.

Comment: hmm .. maybe you'll need another service